# Why is my method never returning anything but null?

Tags: java, android, multidimensional-array, adt, path-finding

IMPORTANT EDIT: I forgot to actually post a large chunk of the code needed to debug this at first. Here are the links:

http://pastebin.com/rxENqzBB

http://pastebin.com/KVXCfys4

http://pastebin.com/Sgv01P8V

http://pastebin.com/mrNVej67

I am currently making a Java application for Android 4.3 using the ADT IDE. The application contains a map of a campus, and outputs directions to the user from the room they are currently in to the room that they wish to go to (both of which having been input by the user). However, I have run into an issue - the following method always returns `null`, even when it shouldn't:

```
Coordinates findCoordsWithRoom(String roomName)
{
    //all floors; 0 -> 1
    for (int z = 0; z < map.length; z++)
    {
        //all rows; 0 -> 10
        for (int y = 0; y < map[z].length; y++)
        {
            //all cols; 0 -> 9
            for (int x = 0; x < map[z][y].length; x++)
            {
                if (dne.equals(map[z][y][x])) { continue; } //if this node is a "dne" node, skip it
                //all valid connections out of this node
                for (int c = 0; c < map[z][y][x].dirArr.length; c++)
                {
                    if (!map[z][y][x].dirArr[c].exists) { continue; }
                    //all rooms on this connection
                    for (int r = 0; r < map[z][y][x].dirArr[c].rooms.length; r++)
                    {
                        String thisRoomName = map[z][y][x].dirArr[c].rooms[r].name;
                        //if this room has the right name
                        if (roomName.equals(thisRoomName))
                        {   //found it
                            return map[z][y][x].coords;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //failed to find it
    return null;
}
```

Even when my debugger tells me that the relevant variables are equal, `if(roomName.equals(thisRoomName))` never evaluates to true, as the program never hits the return statement therein.

This is the `map` variable:

```
Node[][][] map =
{
    {   //first floor
        //00   01   02   03   04   05   06   07   08   09 <-x/y:
        {dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, cls, dne, dne, dne, dne}, //00
        {dne, dne, dne, dne,  oc,  cl,  cf, dne, dne, dne}, //01
        {dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne}, //02
        {dne, dne, dne, dne, og2,  g4,  gc,  g2, gs1, dne}, //03
        {dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, gs2,  g1,  g3, dne}, //04
        {dne, ot3, dne, ot1,  op, dne, og1, gal, dne, dne}, //05
        {dne, ot4, dne, dne, dne, dne,  a2,  a1, dne, dne}, //06
        {dne,  t3, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne,  a3,  as, dne}, //07
        {dne,  t1, tl1, ot2, dne, dne, dne,  a4, dne, dne}, //08
        { ts,  t2, tl2, ot5, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne}, //09
        {dne,  t4, tls, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne}, //10
    },
    {   //second floor
        //00   01   02   03   04   05   06   07   08   09 <-x/y:
        {dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, CLS, dne, dne, dne, dne}, //00
        {dne, dne, dne, dne, dne,  CL,  C2,  C4, dne, dne}, //01
        {dne, dne, dne, dne, dne,  C1,  C3,  C5, dne, dne}, //02
        {dne, dne, dne, dne, dne,  G4, GC1,  G3, GS1, dne}, //03
        {dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, GC2, dne,  G1,  G2, dne}, //04
        {dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, GS2, dne, GAL, dne, dne}, //05
        {dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne,  A5,GALS, dne, dne}, //06
        {dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne,  A3,  A1, dne, dne}, //07
        {dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne,  A2,  AS, dne}, //08
        { TS,  T4,  T3, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne}, //09
        {dne, TLS,  TL, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne}, //10
    }
};
```

`dne` is just `static Node dne = new Node();`

Here is a link to the constructions of all the objects in `map`, as it is much too large to paste in directly: http://pastebin.com/Qad46gHh

A `Coordinates` object essentially is just a container for three `int`s - `x`, `y`, and `z`, and is constructed with `public Coordinates (int z, int y, int x)`.

This is where the method is being called from:

```
public ArrayList<Coordinates> makeRoute(String start, String end)
{
    destination = end;
    ArrayList<Coordinates> newCoordArr1 = new ArrayList<Coordinates>();
    ArrayList<Coordinates> newCoordArr2 = new ArrayList<Coordinates>();
    ArrayList<Coordinates> newCoordArr3 = new ArrayList<Coordinates>();
    Coordinates startCoords = world.findCoordsWithRoom(start);
    Coordinates endCoords = world.findCoordsWithRoom(end);
    ArrayList<Coordinates> path = world.makePath(startCoords, endCoords, newCoordArr1, newCoordArr2, newCoordArr3);
    return path;
}
```

Where, for instance, `start` is "104" and `end` is "204" (attached to `g2` and `G2` respectively), but `startCoords` and `endCoords` are both `null`.

Here is a link to the pathfinding algorithm: http://pastebin.com/NVhSU06w

In the interest of not appearing to be question-spamming in order to draw attention to this, I'd like to state for the record that the other two questions in my question history, while both regarding this same project, are regarding different problems I have encountered with said project.

Comment: I see neither "104" nor "204" in your map.

Comment: 204 is just a dne room, then if the room you are looking for is 204 the code will skip it

Comment: @xgc1986 Clarified what I meant

Comment: @Karakuri Clarified what I meant

Comment: wouldn't it be simpler to keep a list of all the rooms?

Comment: @njzk2 I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: you have a complex 3d map and you search the room by name in all the coordinates of the map. wouldn't it be simpler to also keep a list of all rooms, so you can easily search for them ? (or even a map indexed on name, that would be faster and much clearer)

Comment: @njzk2 Ah, I see what you mean. No, that would not be better, as the point of this is simply to get where the room it, but to direct the user to the room. I use a pathfinding algorithm (A*) to do this, hence the 3D map.

Comment: this search is not A*, it is depth-first, and it returns only the coords for the room, not the path.

Comment: @njzk2 Er, what? Yes, this only returns the coordinates, but the pathfinding method here: http://pastebin.com/NVhSU06w does return the path

Comment: my point exactly. this methods only gets you the room coords for the name, but its complexity is `o(x*y*z)`, which is more than the hoped complexity of the A* search.

Comment: @njzk2 I'm not sure what you are suggesting, then - I can't just skip right to the pathfinding, as the input to this is a `String` object, while the input to the pathfinding is a `Coordinates` object.

Comment: 2 possibilities: modify your pathfinding to search for a String at these Coordinates instead of a Coordinates, or add a reference collection of rooms to get the coordinate more rapidly.

Comment: I also think there is something inheritly flawed in your design: Nodes are not aware of the room they are in, only the adjacent Nodes are.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51768/discussion-between-njzk2-and-invictus)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wouldn't it be simpler to keep a list of all the rooms? –  njzk2 Apr 30 at 16:10`

Well, I followed this suggestion (made an ArrayList of a custom Pair class, and stored expected input-output in there), and this problem with the project, at least, is solved. I've still no idea what the problem was, unfortunately, but it's part is working, at least.